# Connecting Actions and objects in two views?

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I link a button with a object label that is in a different view?
Do I need to create the property in both header files and if not how do I link the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of changing a text label from the previous view in the navigation stack:

```
int controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
PreviousViewController *view = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:controllers - 2];
view.questionLabel.text = [self.questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a step back and change the way you think about the way you design your code. A button should never change a label in another view. This is against the MVC design pattern. I would suggest you to take a look at this. http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969